# fuelphpで複数のURLを1つのコントローラーに結びつける方法

Tags: php, fuelphp

```
test/codemaseter
test/codemaseter/
test/codemaseter/dept/*
```

のように`test/codemaseter`以下に来る全てのURLパターンを
1つのコントローラーに集約させたいのですがそう言ったことは可能でしょうか？

上の3つは例で`id=xxx12313`のように`get`パラムで不定形の文字列が来るパターンもあるので、以下全て許容して対象のコントローラー1つにアクセスするようにすることは可能でしょうか？

下記のような記述で大丈夫かと思ったのですが、`codemaseter`以下の`/`の有無が上手く判定できないのとこの場合`:any`が何を指し示すかよく分からないので怖くて使えないです。

```
'test/codemaseter(/:any)' =>  array(array('GET' , new Router::get('programming/test')))
```

Answer (score 0):

routerを使うのもありですが、htaccessでの制御をすることも考えられます。